# Boolean Union Doesn't Work

Tags: modifiers

All I'm looking to do is union join two meshes together. They're not overly large or complex and I can't find any faults with them (Mind you I'm new to this). If anyone can help I'd be very grateful! It shouldn't take long at all for anyone with experience.
[The file is linked here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5ZmNMcjHImOQmQzTndUYlVFcjg)

Answer (score 2):

The inner mesh *Ear Deco* has overlapping faces.

1. Go into edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Select <kbd>B</kbd> and hide <kbd>H</kbd> the outermost faces. You will find additional faces inside the mesh.
   [image: faces inside mesh]
2. Go into face selection mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> > <kbd>F</kbd>, select the unnecessary internal faces and delete them <kbd>X</kbd>.
   [image: delete faces]
3. The boolean modifier will now work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's been huge help and providing both these excellent instructions and a final model is great! It means I can take the model onto the next stage and still learn from you. I didn't know you could hide external faces, thanks! :D